# After running the Springboot application table is not getting created in my sql databse

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Application class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HotelServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HotelServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Entity Class

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import com.infy.HotelService.dto.HotelDto;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="hotel",schema="hotelservice")
public class HotelEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="location")
    private String location;
    @Column(name="desc")
    private String desc;
    
    
    public HotelDto convertToDto()
    {
        HotelDto hd = new HotelDto();
        hd.setId(this.getId());
        hd.setName(this.getName());
        hd.setLocation(this.getLocation());
        hd.setDescription(this.getDesc());
        return hd;
        
    }

}
```

DTO class

```
package com.infy.HotelService.dto;
import com.infy.HotelService.model.HotelModel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class HotelDto extends HotelModel{
    
    private Integer id;
//  private String name;
//  private String location;
//  private String description;

}
```

Model class

```
package com.infy.HotelService.model;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class HotelModel {
    
    private String name;
    private String location;
    private String description;
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotelservice
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/microservice
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql: true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.profiles.active = dev
server.port=8082
server.servlet.context-path=/HotelService
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.14</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.infy.HotelService</groupId>
    <artifactId>HotelService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>HotelService</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

After running the Springboot application table is not getting created in mysql database

Getting no error but sql query is not executed.

I have mentioned the schema as hotelservice in database.

While testing the api in postman I am getting 404 not found error

Comment: Without an error message it is nearly impossible to tell you why the table is not created in mysql

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using? Please add your dependencies (your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`. .

Comment: i have updated the pom.xml please check and suggest !!

Comment: I have added pom.xml into question

Comment: replace `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`

Comment: that is also not working